# Class constructors: getting error 'Name does not exist in current context'

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, overloading, this, class-constructors

I'm currently going through an online class about class constructors. and it's giving the error name 'name' does not exist in current context.

```
class Forest
{

// first constructor
public Forest(string biome, string name)
{

  this.Name = name;
  this.Biome = biome;
  Age = 0;

}
//second constructor

public Forest(string biome) : this(name, "Unknown")
{

  Console.WriteLine("Name property not specified. Value defaulted to 'Unknown'");

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `biome` instead of `name` in second constructor, like

```
public Forest(string biome) : this(biome, "Unknown")
{                  //^^^^^^ here biome is know to compiler from parameter of second constructor, not name.

  Console.WriteLine("Name property not specified. Value defaulted to 'Unknown'");

}
```

In your case you are calling first constructor from second constructor. When ever you create instance of `Forest` class with only `biome` value, then it will call second constructor and `: this(name, "Unknown")` execute first constructor.

---

You are using constructor chaining using `this` operator. [From MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-constructors)

> A constructor can invoke another constructor in the same object by
>   using the `this` keyword. Like base, `this` can be used with or without
>   parameters, and any parameters in the constructor are available as
>   parameters to this, or as part of an expression

Comment: @Hopeless, MSDN docs explained this term very well. I would request you to go through it once.

Comment: Sorry did not see your answer. You posted first.

Comment: @panoskarajohn, no problem. :)

Comment: @Hopeless, if my answer helped, then don't miss to accept it.